# Angular, Login State, and Conditional Includes

Tags: angularjs

My index.html looks like this:

```
<div ng-include src="'common/header.html'"></div></div>
<div id="view" ng-view></div>
```

However, I don't want the header.html to show up when the user is not logged in. `AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()` is available to use. How do I make this work?

Do I need to broadcast the login event from the `LoginController` so that `HeaderIncludeController` can update itself or something? Seems really messy...

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div ng-include src="'common/header.html'" ng-if="loggedIn()"></div>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.loggedIn = AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn;
```

Comment: What controllers scope would that property go inside of? Do I need to add ng-controller to my ng-include line? Would assigning the function to the property make it update when the route changes? I tried something like that already and it gets set when the app loads but doesn't change after that.

Comment: if you have some controller defined above `ng-view`, then it will be that one, if you don't have one like that, you can change it to `$rootScope.loggedIn` and place in inside `app.run`